# My Flutter Android folder shows an error and I don't understand where the error is

Tags: java, android, flutter, geolocation, redhat

There one pop up about Java that tell me to update it and I accidentally clicked on it. I am doing Geo location apps and after that, my Android folder got error, like this.

```
[C:\myapp\android\app\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java:19: error: cannot access OnCompletionListener
    flutterEngine.getPlugins().add(new com.baseflow.geolocator.GeolocatorPlugin());
                              ^
  class file for com.baseflow.geolocator.OnCompletionListener not found
1 error

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 21s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1][1]
```

Comment: Try to upgrade your plugins, especially `geolocator` one. It seems that the error is within this plugin

Comment: I already upgrade my plugins just now, but still the same error appeared. I don't know where is the actual error come from :(

Comment: Try executing `flutter clean` and rerun the application

Comment: It's work!! thankyou very much Mr!!

Comment: I added it as an answer, please mark it as accepted.